# Error: could not create the Java Virtual Machine Can't allocate enough memory to Minecraft server

Tags: java, minecraft

I have currently been trying to setup a minecraft server on an Intel Nuc that I have it has 8gb of ram this will be important later. I used to be running it on my main desktop and was able to tun it with 4gb of ram allocated to it, that computer had 16gb of ram though. My initial problem was that I could not allocated more than 1500M of ram to it using the following command in a .bat file;

```
java -Xms2048M -Xmx2048M -jar server.jar
```

I then decided to run it in command prompt and received the following error.

```
java -Xmx2048M -Xms2048M -jar server.jar nogui
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for 2097152KB object heap
```

I did some research on the error and found that I might need to add a system variable for.

```
Variable name: _JAVA_OPTIONS
Variable value: -Xmx512M
```

So I did that and it still didn't work.
Then I decided to install 64bit Java as I did not know if I had it or not and that is when I received the error;

```
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

So after that i tried to figure out which version I had so I ran the command;

```
java -version
```

and received this:

```
Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -xms512M
Unrecognized option: -xms512M
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

Whenever I try to run any Java commands or the server this is what I get and this is after I had removed the system variable.
I am not super knowledgeable about Java and I am just trying to run a minecraft server so if you need any more information please ask.

Comment: What OS is on the NUC? Is `java` an alias?

Comment: Does your NUC run Windows or Linux?

Comment: Have you tried rebooting after you changed the environment?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of the feedback but I got it working it turns out I just needed to restart a few times and uninstall the version of Java I had and get 64-bit Java. Also if your still curious I am running windows on the NUC